# Why is my text input field not aligning to the bottom left of my phone?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I thought adding an `Align` widget and setting the alignment to `bottomLeft` would do the trick, but for some reason when I run the app on my phone (Galaxy S21) there is about an inch of white space below the text input field.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(

                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  ElevatedButton(

                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(

                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(

                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(

                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(

                  ),
                  Expanded(

                  )
                ]
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[

                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(

                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(

                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **mainAxisSize** with **MainAxisSize.min** and set add **Directionality** widget and make **textDirection** LeftToRight.

```
Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min ,

              children: [
                 

              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```